# How to remove adjacent date strings in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, replacement

Given a list as

```
list = {"2018-9-1",1,2,3,"2018-9-2","2018-9-3",4,5,6,"2018-9-5",7,8,9,"2018-9-6","2018-9-7",10,11,12,"2018-9-8",13,14,15,"2018-9-9",16,17,18}
```

or

```
list = {"2018-9-1","a","b","c","2018-9-2","2018-9-3","d","e","f","2018-9-5","h","i","j","2018-9-6","2018-9-7","k","l","m","2018-9-8","n","o","p","2018-9-9","q","r","s"}
```

how can adjacent date strings being pruned to get this result?

```
{"2018-9-1",1,2,3,"2018-9-3",4,5,6,"2018-9-5",7,8,9,"2018-9-7",10,11,12,"2018-9-8",13,14,15,"2018-9-9",16,17,18}
```

or

```
{"2018-9-1","a","b","c","2018-9-3","d","e","f","2018-9-5","h","i","j","2018-9-7","k","l","m","2018-9-8","n","o","p","2018-9-9","q","r","s"}
```

such that the function `Partition` could be applied properly.
Thanks!

Comment: Something like: `SequenceReplace[list, {_String, s_String} -> s]`?

Comment: @Call Woll Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. One way uses [`SequenceReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace). First define a `dateStringQ` predicate:

```
dateStringQ = StringMatchQ[DatePattern[{"Year","Month","Day"}]];
```

Your examples:

```
list1 = {
    "2018-9-1",1,2,3,"2018-9-2","2018-9-3",4,5,6,"2018-9-5",7,8,9,
    "2018-9-6","2018-9-7",10,11,12,"2018-9-8",13,14,15,"2018-9-9",16,17,18
};

list2 = {
    "2018-9-1","a","b","c","2018-9-2","2018-9-3","d","e","f","2018-9-5",
    "h","i","j","2018-9-6","2018-9-7","k","l","m","2018-9-8","n","o","p",
    "2018-9-9","q","r","s"
};
```

Using [`SequenceReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace):

```
SequenceReplace[
    list1,
    {_String?dateStringQ, s_String?dateStringQ} :> s
]

SequenceReplace[
    list2,
    {_String?dateStringQ, s_String?dateStringQ} :> s
]
```

> {"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 7, 8, 9, "2018-9-7", 
>   10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17, 18}
>
> {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f", "2018-9-5", "h", "i", 
>   "j", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p", "2018-9-9", "q",
>   "r", "s"}

Comment: why `SequenceReplace[list2, {_String?StringMatchQ[
    DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]], 
   s_String?StringMatchQ[DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]]} :> s]` doesnot work?

Comment: @Jerry The issue is precedence, `_String?StringMatchQ[DataPattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]]` is parsed as `(_String?StringMatchQ)[DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]]` not `_String?(StringMatchQ[DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]])`.

Comment: I see, Thanks very much!:)

Answer (score 3):

`SequenceReplace` is suitable, as @CarlWoll pointed out in the comment. But it needs further elaboration to work with both of your lists. Below is my version

```
stringPattern = RegularExpression["\\d{4}-\\d-\\d"];
stringMatchQ = If[StringQ[#], StringMatchQ[#, stringPattern], False] &;
rule = {a_?stringMatchQ, b_?stringMatchQ} :> b;

SequenceReplace[list1, rule]
SequenceReplace[list2, rule]
```

> {"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 7, 8, 9, "2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17, 18}
>
> {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f", "2018-9-5", "h", "i", "j", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p", "2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"}

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 =
  {"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-2", "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 
   7, 8, 9, "2018-9-6", "2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 
   15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17, 18};

list2 =
  {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-2", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f", 
   "2018-9-5", "h", "i", "j", "2018-9-6", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", 
   "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p", "2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"};

dateStringQ = StringMatchQ[DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]];
```

Grabbing the @Carl Woll's `dateStringQ` definition and using `SequenceCases`:

```
patts1 = {s : {__String?dateStringQ} :> Last@s, s : {__?NumericQ} :> s};

patts2 = {s : {__String?dateStringQ} :> Last@s, s : {__String?LetterQ} :> s};

Flatten[Riffle[#1, #2] & @@ (SequenceCases[list1, #] & /@ patts1)]
```

> {"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 7, 8, 9,
> "2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17,
> 18}

```
Flatten[Riffle[#1, #2] & @@ (SequenceCases[list2, #] & /@ patts2)]
```

> {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f", "2018-9-5",
> "h", "i", "j", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p",
> "2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"}

Answer (score 1):

```
la =
  {"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-2", "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 
   7, 8, 9, "2018-9-6", "2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 
   15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17, 18};

lb =
  {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-2", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f", 
   "2018-9-5", "h", "i", "j", "2018-9-6", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", 
   "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p", "2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
foo = Flatten @ SequenceSplit[#, x : {__String?(StringLength[#] > 1 &)} :> Last[x]] &;

foo @ la
```

{"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 7, 8, 9,
"2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17,
18}

```
foo @ lb
```

{"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f", "2018-9-5",
"h", "i", "j", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p",
"2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"}

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

alist = {"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-2", "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, 
   "2018-9-5", 7, 8, 9, "2018-9-6", "2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, 
   "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17, 18};

blist = {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-2", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", 
   "f", "2018-9-5", "h", "i", "j", "2018-9-6", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", 
   "m", "2018-9-8", "n", "o", "p", "2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"};

f = SequenceReplace[#, { _String?(DateObjectQ@*DateObject), 
     t_String?(DateObjectQ@*DateObject)} :> t] &;

f /@ {alist, blist}
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"2018-9-1", 1, 2, 3, "2018-9-3", 4, 5, 6, "2018-9-5", 7, 8, 9,
> "2018-9-7", 10, 11, 12, "2018-9-8", 13, 14, 15, "2018-9-9", 16, 17,
> 18}, {"2018-9-1", "a", "b", "c", "2018-9-3", "d", "e", "f",
> "2018-9-5", "h", "i", "j", "2018-9-7", "k", "l", "m", "2018-9-8",
> "n", "o", "p", "2018-9-9", "q", "r", "s"}}